# Setting defaultValues on the fly for Select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am trying to follow this sample:
https://react-select.com/home

I have defined two following arrays:

```
const [selectedAccountTypes, setSelectedAccountTypes] = useState([]);
const [allAccountTypes, setAllAccountTypes] = useState([]);
```

I set the values in following function when a user click a button:

```
const onAccountChanged = async (val) => {
console.log(val); 
setSearchedAccount(val);

console.log('onAccountChanged'); 
console.log(searchedAccountValue); 

const accounts = await getAccountTypeLookupList();

var options = accounts.data.map((o) => ({
  label: o.name,
  value: o.id,
  number: o.accountNumber
}))   
console.log(options); 

setAllAccountTypes(options);
setSelectedAccountTypes(options);

console.log(options);
console.log(setSelectedAccountTypes);

return options;
};
```

And my component:

```
<Select
placeholder='First select account above'
isMulti
cacheOptions
defaultValue ={selectedAccountTypes}  
options={allAccountTypes}/>
```

I would expect all to be selected in this scenario nut nothing is default selected. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the timing. At time I set the selected values the control has not finished rendering the control. I ended up making a useEffect on the array, and in that I set default selected.

Answer (score 0):

Set the value to selectedAccountTypes, then onChange call the setSelectedAccountTypes to update it.

Comment: But is that not what I am doing?